# Restoring prerelease packages with NuGet

Tags: .net, nuget

On our build server I'm trying to all the packages in a solution from the command line using NuGet 2.7. According to [this Microsoft post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/08/22/improved-package-restore.aspx) it should be as easy as

```
nuget.exe restore Foo.sln
```

This mostly works except it can't find a number of packages:

```
Unable to find version '1.5.0-beta' of package 'Google.Apis.Authentication'.
Unable to find version '1.5.0.71-beta' of package 'Google.Apis.Analytics.v3'.
Unable to find version '1.5.0-beta' of package 'Google.Apis'.
```

My guess is that it's not a coincidence that these are the only prerelease packages in my packages.config files. According to [the docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Restore_command) `nuget.exe restore` is pretty much the only command that doesn't have a `-Prerelease` option, so how can I restore prerelease packages?

Answer (score -1):

I'm somewhat surprised. Restoring prerelease packages usually works for me. And the package you are talking about seems to still exist if you address it directly.

However, there is a difference between your prerelease packages and mine - it seems that Google.Apis.Authentication/1.5.0-beta is now an 'unlisted' package, meaning it won't show up in search results.

It may be that NuGet has a bug where it won't restore unlisted packages. At least, I assume it is a bug. You've probably solved this by now, but if not, try opening an issue on NuGet issue tracker (nuget.codeplex.com).

Comment: What is the bug number for this?

Comment: Nevermind, apparently you get the same error messages when [mono doesn’t have all the nuget certs imported](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/335#issuecomment-3380328).